# jekyllrb based website not loading css effects

Tags: html, css, jekyll

I am trying to create a portfolio by combining two themes.

The first theme and basis for the project is [this](https://statichunt.com/themes/jekyll-minimal-resume) one. I like the whole moving stars effect so that is why I decided for this one. [image: stars]

The second theme is [this](https://statichunt.com/themes/jekyll-freelancer) one. From this theme I want to take the grid system with the cards and implement it into the first one. [image: grid].

To do this, I have copied all the files from the second project that I think are relevant into the first one and I kind of got what I want. But, somehow the full effects are not implemented. My project can be accessed from [this](https://github.com/simonovskifilip/web-first-try) repository.

To show an example:
[image: example]
One post looks like this. Ideally it should be only one picture which when opened should show the full version of the post. I tried to copy the css variable into the html file in a `<style> COPIED HERE </style>`.

I am an absolute beginner and my goal is just to get a working webpage. Could someone hint me why I am not getting the expected effects?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess because your post does not include your HTML and CSS and your page isn't showing the non-working sample site from your screenshot.

The grid with the images uses the [Bootstrap grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) as you can see on the `col-sm-4` below.

Here's the [file that includes bootstrap](https://github.com/jeromelachaud/freelancer-theme/blob/89203dcb44e850811e79061065b87bfb25f9b28d/_includes/js.html), _includes/js.html:

```
<!-- jQuery Version 1.11.0 -->
<script src="{{ " js/jquery-1.11.0.js" }}"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="{{ " js/bootstrap.min.js" }}"></script>
...
```

You may need to inspect the grid part even more:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item">
    <a href="#portfolioModal-1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
        <div class="caption">
            <div class="caption-content">
                <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img src="img/portfolio/cabin.png" class="img-responsive" alt="image-alt">
    </a>
</div>
...
```